# I have written the Henon iterate code

Tags: python-2.7, iteration

```
def HenonIterate_Plot(x0,y0,a,b,alpha,gamma,n):

    iterates = np.zeros([n,2])  # This makes an nx2 matrix i.e n rows, 2 columns, where the first column stores x coordinates,
                                # and the 2nd column stores y coordinates
    iterates[0,0] = x0 # Store the initial x-coordinate
    iterates[0,1] = y0 # Store the initial y-coordinate
    for jj in range(1,n):
        iterates[1:] = HenonMap(iterates[n:],1)

    return iterates
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: it gives me Type Error when i try to plot .   x0 = 0
y0 = 0
a = 1.4
b = 0.3
alpha = 1
gamma = 1
n = 10000
iterates = HenonIterate_Plot(x0,y0,a,b,alpha,gamma,n)
plt.scatter(iterates[2:,0],iterates[2:,1],s=5)

Comment: def HenonMap(pt, a, b, alpha, gamma):
    # pt is a numpy array with two elements, pt[0] and pt[1], representing x_n and y_n respectively.  
    
    xn = 0
    yn = 0
    xn1 = 1
    yn1 = 0
    return np.array([xn1,yn1])

Comment: Please edit your question add the information in your comments, also add a real question.